# Как загрузить данные из файла *.txt в базу данных mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Данные в файле *.txt записаны в формате `key \t value \t fruit \n`, пытаюсь использовать команду

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\user\Documents\*.txt' INTO TABLE phonenumbers;
```

mysql ругается следующим образом:

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

Что мне делать? Я в отчаянии.

Comment: что-то с правами пользователя, если я правильно понял. попробуйте их расширить

Comment: @dasauser а как?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361962/error-2068-hy000-load-data-local-infile-file-request-rejected-due-to-restrict

Comment: знал бы точный ответ - обязательно бы написал, а так только направил. извиняюсь за обнадеживание...

Comment: @dasauser спасибо! а где находится файл конфигурации сервера на windows? В одном из ответов сказано, что его надо 'подкрутить'.

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте всё про серверные переменные `secure_file_priv` и `local_infile`, а также о привилегии `FILE`. Кстати, почему Вы используете `LOCAL`?